# how to make flutter tab bar expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I'm trying to make a colorful tab view, it look expanded if there are more items in tab, but if it is single item it doesn't look good.
my tab look like below now

[image]

how can I make it look like this?

[image]

this is my code, I've tried expanded widget but it didn't work. please help

```
PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar() {
return AppBar(
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
    child: _buildTabBar(),
  ),
  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('dash_board')),
  actions: _buildActions(context),
);}


Widget _buildTabBar() {
return Observer(builder: (context) {
  var items = _dashStore.dashData?.data?.dashboardShopsModels;
  if (items == null) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  } else {
    return Expanded(
      child: ColoredBox(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 26, 74),
        child: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorWeight: 4,
          indicatorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 105),  
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,             
          tabs: [
            for (var item in items) Tab(text: '${item.shopName}'),
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
});}
```

Answer (score 2):

wrap TabBar with SizedBox

```
ColoredBox(
  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 26, 74),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: TabBar(..),
  ),
)
```